# How to store special characters in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, parquet

I've been playing around with Spark, Hive and Parquet, I have some data in my Hive table and here is how it looks like ( warning french language ahead ) :

```
Bloqu� � l'arriv�e      NULL
Probl�me de connexion   Bloqu� en hub
```

Obviously there's something wrong here.

What I do is : I read a teradata table as a dataframe with spark, I store it as a parquet file and then I use this file to store it to hive, here's my create table script :

```
CREATE TABLE `table`(
   `lib` VARCHAR(255),
   `libelle_sous_cause` VARCHAR(255),
   )
 STORED AS PARQUET
 LOCATION
   'hdfs://location';
```

I don't really know what cause this, it might be caused by some special encoding between Teradata > parquet or Parquet > Hive, I'm not sure.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that out, the solution was to simply use `STRING` instead of `VARCHAR`

```
CREATE TABLE `table`(
   `lib` STRING,
   `libelle_sous_cause` STRING,
   )
 STORED AS PARQUET
 LOCATION
   'hdfs://location';
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem when doing sqoop from Teradata to Hadoop. When extracting from Teradata, in the `SELECT`, please try wrapping your `varchar` columns, that may have this issue, with this line:

```
SELECT
NAME,
AGE,
TRIM(CAST(TRANSLATE(COLUMNOFINTEREST USING latin_to_unicode WITH ERROR) AS VARCHAR(50)))
FROM
TABLENAME;
```

`COLUMNOFINTEREST` is your column that would have special characters.

Let me know if that works.